# The secondary linkage in my webpage cannot display the options in Django 1.10

Tags: python, html, django

I use [smart_selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects) to realize secondary linkage in Django admin page. Succeed! When I choose one university, only the colleges those belong to the university can be chosen.

But, when it comes to the form in webpage, the second level form cannot display any option.
This is the wrong webpage:

[image]

Here are the codes:

> models.py

```
class StudentModel(models.Model):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (('M','男'),('F','女'),)

    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='姓名',max_length=20)
    gender = models.CharField(blank = True,max_length=4,choices = GENDER_CHOICES,verbose_name='性别')
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(verbose_name='出生日期',blank=True,null=True)
    age = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='年龄',default=0)
    highschool = models.ForeignKey(SeniorHighSchoolModel,verbose_name='高中名称')
    university = models.ForeignKey(UniversityModel,verbose_name='大学名称')
    college = ChainedForeignKey(CollegeModel,chained_field='university',chained_model_field='university',show_all=False,blank=True,null=True,verbose_name='学院名称')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

> forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import StudentModel

class LoggingForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = StudentModel
    fields=['name','gender','date_of_birth','age','highschool','university','college']
```

> logging.html

```
<form action="" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{{form.as_p}}
<input type='submit' />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an resolution,just add {{form.media.js}} in logging.html.

```
 <form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    **{{form.media.js}}**
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type='submit' />
    <a>You will recieve an email from us.</a>
 </form>
```

The answer is found in this question:
[How to use django smart-selects with modelform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39801337/how-to-use-django-smart-selects-with-modelform)

Thanks for the edition from Donald Duck.